# java - how to find if the machine has Ipv6 interface?

Tags: java, tcp

Is it possible to determine if the machine has IPV6 enabled using any Java api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InetAddress a = InetAddress.getByName(“www.sun.com”);
if (a instanceof Inet6Address) {
    Inet6Address a2 = (Inet6Address) a;
    if (a2.isIPv4CompatibleAddress()) {
        ...
    } if (
        a2.isLinkLocalAddress()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I used combination of this and one from @bemace. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the NetworkInterface class.  It has methods for getting all the machine's network interfaces including virtual ones.  You could look at the InetAddress for each interface and use `inetAddress.getAddress().length` to check the number of bytes in the IP to distinguish between IPv4 and IPv6.